# How to get numbers from string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, numbers, expression

I have this string

```
[23,22,17][17,2][23][3,29][][10,43,6][7][32,17,6][][][23,49,12][14,40,15][34,41,32][4,7,19][9,27][17][31,36,45][][32][40,27,25]
```

obtained from json and i saved it into ArrayList like this:

```
 ArrayList<?> listAdress=(ArrayList<?>)jobj.get("adress");
```

I want to take only the numbers and save the numbers in brackets into a vector like this.

```
 v[]={23,22,18}
 v[]={17,2}
```

I tried to get only the numbers, but i dont know how to take the numbers untill you find ]

Someone know how to?

Comment: `listAdress.get(0) is string "[23,22,17]"`?

Comment: `^[\,\[\]]?(([0-9]*)[\,\[\]]*)*?$`

Comment: For the first question i get error:
     `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`


And the second doesnt give me what i want

Comment: Please clarify exactly what your code must produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testStr = "[23,22,17][17,2][23][3,29][][10,43,6][7][32,17,6][][][23,49,12][14,40,15][34,41,32][4,7,19][9,27][17][31,36,45][][32][40,27,25]";
    ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] resTmp = testStr.split("\\[|\\]\\[");  // First split input into vectors

    for (String vecDef: resTmp)    // Then split each vector into a String[]
        result.add(vecDef.split(","));

    for (String[] s : result) {    // result = ArrayList with an element for each vector
        for (String ss : s)        // Each element is an array of Strings each being a number
            System.out.print(ss + " ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the regex you'll need for your problem :

```
(\d*,*)*
```

A link for [explanation](https://regex101.com/r/hZ4eU3/1) of this regex

here follows the java method to get the arrays of numbers :

```
public static List<String []> getNumberArrays (String toBeProcessed){
        List<String[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d*,*)*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(toBeProcessed);
        while(m.find()){
            String[] a ;
            a =m.group(0).split(",");
            // next statement for avoiding the printing of empty arrays
            if(a.length>=2) 
                listOfArrays.add(a);
        }
        return listOfArrays;

    }
```

**Test code :**

```
    String x = "[23,22,17][17,2][23][3,29][][10,43,6][7][32,17,6][][][23,49,12][14,40,15][34,41,32][4,7,19][9,27][17][31,36,45][][32][40,27,25]" ;
    List<String[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    listOfArrays = getNumberArrays(x);
    for(String[] a :listOfArrays){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
     }
```

**Output :**

```
[23, 22, 17]
[17, 2]
[3, 29]
[10, 43, 6]
[32, 17, 6]
[23, 49, 12]
[14, 40, 15]
[34, 41, 32]
[4, 7, 19]
[9, 27]
[31, 36, 45]
[40, 27, 25]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a Regex but I'm not sure it's the only or the best way to go for such a simple parsing.

Here a quick (and not so safe) code:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String input = "[23,22,17][17,2][23][3,29][][10,43,6][7][32,17,6][][][23,49,12][14,40,15][34,41,32][4,7,19][9,27][17][31,36,45][][32][40,27,25]";
        input = input.substring(1, input.length()-1);
        String[] vectors = input.split("\\]\\[");

        for(String vector : vectors)
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\"", vector));
        }
     }
}
```

Output:

> "23,22,17"
>   "17,2"
>   "23"
>   "3,29"
>   ""
>   "10,43,6"
>   "7"
>   "32,17,6"
>   ""
>   ""
>   "23,49,12"
>   "14,40,15"
>   "34,41,32"
>   "4,7,19"
>   "9,27"
>   "17"
>   "31,36,45"
>   ""
>   "32"
>   "40,27,25"

The thing is: you have to make sure that the string provided as an input is always well formatted (beginning with a [, ending with a ], and made of segments beginning with [ and ending with ]). Yet it's almost the same story with regular expressions (invalid input = no outputs, or *partial* outputs).

Once you have your strings with numbers separated by commas, the rest of the job is easy (you can split again and then parse to Integers).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void importarCorreos() throws Exception{
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ClientRequest cr = new       ClientRequest("http://di002.edv.uniovi.es/~delacal/tew/1415/practica02/servicio_correos.php");

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        String result = cr.get(String.class).getEntity(String.class);

        CorreosService service = Factories.services.createCorreosService();
        //Imprimimos todo el flujo JSON recibido en formato cadena.
        System.out.println(result);
        //Procesamos el texto JSON y lo pasamos a formato SIMPLE-JSON
        Object obj=JSONValue.parse(result);
        JSONArray correos = (JSONArray)obj;
        ListIterator li = correos.listIterator();
        while(li.hasNext()){
            JSONObject jobj =(JSONObject) li.next();
            Correo c = new Correo();
            c.setFechaHora( Long.parseLong(jobj.get("fechahora").toString()));
            c.setAsunto(jobj.get("asunto").toString());
            c.setCuerpo(jobj.get("cuerpo").toString());
            c.setCarpeta( Integer.parseInt(jobj.get("carpeta").toString()));
            c.setLogin_user(usuario.getLogin());
            ArrayList<?> listaDestinatarios=(ArrayList<?>)jobj.get("destinatarios");
            service.saveCorreo(c);

        }

   }
```

This is my function, mainly i obtained a json with mails from this url. I create a new mail with the fields from that url. But one of field from Mails class is mail_contacts where you should save the adresses from each contact like a vector [1,2,3] this is the id from  the adress.

So how can i get the numbers into [ ], and save it into the fields mail_contacts what its a array.

I can save it like this:

```
     c.setMailAdress(Here i want an array with the numbers from each [])
```

Answer (score 0):

@ulix

Ok, this give the exit that i want:

00:53:20,413 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) 23 22 17

00:53:20,414 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) 17 2

00:53:20,414 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) 23

00:53:20,416 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) 3 29

00:53:20,416 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6)

00:53:20,417 INFO  [stdout] (default task-6) 10 43 6

But i want to save each position from string into an array of int, like int v[]={23,22,17}